# How To Compare Two DateTimePicker with JQuery?

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

I wanna compare two datetimepicker with jquery. If start_date > end_date will alert "Your end date input incorrect" How to solve this. I have tried with this code, but did not work.

```
    var startDate;
     $("#waktu_mulai").datetimepicker({
                 timepicker:true,
                 closeOnDateSelect:false,
                 closeOnTimeSelect: true,
                 initTime: true,
                 format: 'd-m-Y H:m',
                 minDate: 0,
                 roundTime: 'ceil',
                 onChangeDateTime: function(dp,$input){
                           startDate = $("#waktu_mulai").val();
                }
    });
    $("#waktu_akhir").datetimepicker({
                 timepicker:true,
                 closeOnDateSelect:false,
                 closeOnTimeSelect: true,
                 initTime: true,
                 format: 'd-m-Y H:m',
                 onClose: function(current_time, $input){
                        var endDate = $("#waktu_akhir").val();
                        if(startDate>endDate){
                               alert('Please select correct date');
                         }
                }
    });
```

Comment: Use caliptal M for month `format: 'd-M-Y H:m',`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `onSelectDate` instead of `onClose` option on second input box (`waktu_akhir`).

```js
var startDate;
$("#waktu_mulai").datetimepicker({
  timepicker: true,
  closeOnDateSelect: false,
  closeOnTimeSelect: true,
  initTime: true,
  format: 'd-m-Y H:m',
  minDate: 0,
  roundTime: 'ceil',
  onChangeDateTime: function(dp, $input) {
    startDate = $("#waktu_mulai").val();
  }
});
$("#waktu_akhir").datetimepicker({
  timepicker: true,
  closeOnDateSelect: false,
  closeOnTimeSelect: true,
  initTime: true,
  format: 'd-m-Y H:m',
  onSelectDate:function(current_time, $input) {
    var endDate = $("#waktu_akhir").val();
    if (startDate > endDate) {
      alert('Please select correct date');
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.20/jquery.datetimepicker.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.20/jquery.datetimepicker.full.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="waktu_mulai" placeholder="Start Date"> -----
<input type="text" id="waktu_akhir" placeholder="End Date">
```

*Note: Don't forget to add JavaScript library properly and JavaScript code must inside `document.ready`.*